# A version of the group ring using direct product rather than direct sum?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be an infinite group. It's (integral) group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ has as its elements the *finite* formal linear combinations 
$$
m_1g_1 + m_2g_2 + \cdots + m_ng_n,\qquad n\in\mathbb{N},\quad m_i\in\mathbb{Z},\quad g_i\in G,
$$
and these are added and multiplied in the obvious way such that the usual ring axioms are satisfied. Thus it has underlying abelian group isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, with one copy for each group element $g\in G$.

I wonder what happens if we replace *direct sum* with *direct product* in the above construction? Can we make the direct product $\prod_{g\in G} \mathbb{Z}$ in the category of abelian groups into a ring by simply defining
$$
(\sum m_gg)(\sum n_h h) = \sum m_g n_h (gh)
$$
and not worrying about whether the sums converge?

And if so, is this ring considered anywhere in the literature? Is it some sort of "completed group ring"?

Comment: Ignoring convergence could not be as useful as one might think because it robs us of the opportunity to use methods from functional analysis etc. For example the space $\ell^2(G)$ is very useful (despite not being an algebra). If we use $\ell^1(G)$ we should get a true algebra, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It looks like you will have trouble with infinite sums on the right hand side. For example, consider $x=\Sigma g$, the sum of all elements of $G$. What is the coefficient of the identity element in the expansion of $x^2$? Looks like it is the order of $G$, which is infinite.

Comment: It seems to me however that I've seen a tiny amount of literature on the formal algebraic calculus of the Dirac distribution (which is exactly Gregory's sum in the case $G = \mathbb{Z}$). As usual, you get into trouble when you try to multiplicatively square the Dirac distribution. However, the formal calculus of $\delta$ and its derivatives can be interesting. See for example the book by Frankel, Lepowsky, and Meurman, *Vertex Operator Algebras and the Monster*. Thus, these direct product analogues might be best seen by pursuing analogies with distributions. 

Comment: I think a keyword you may be interested in is "Hahn series". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series  

Comment: @Gregory: Thanks, I had an inkling this might be a stupid question, but couldn't see why! If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it. @Everyone else: Thanks for making the question seem less stupid. I'll look into these references.

Comment: This can be made to work for semigroups in which each element has only finitely many factorizations of length 2, eg, the free monoid. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I will make my comment into an answer. The multiplication is not well defined, because of infinite sums :-)